# form submit event on button click not firing in IE 9.0.11

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In IE 9.0.11 only, when i hit enter in the text box then submit event is firing just fine. If i click the search button, then "submit" event is not firing. The page is submitting to itself at this point. Clear click event is firing normal here.

I have IE 9.0.12 and it is behaving normal.

HTML Form

```
<form name="frmCollegeReview" method="Post" action="">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%"
    id="table3">
        <tr>
            <td width="15%" class="lineitem0">College Key</td>
            <td width="85%" class="lineitem0">
                <input maxlength="6" name="txtCollegeKey" size="15" class="field" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="85%">
                <input type="image" src="/pics/btn/btn_search.gif" alt="Search" id="formSubmit">
                <a href="#" id="formReset">
                    <img border="0" src="/pics/btn/btn_clear.gif">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

jquery submit event

```
$("#" + CollegeReview._enum.ClearFormButton).live("click", function () {
    $("input[name='" + CollegeReview._enum.CollegeKey + "']").val(0);
    return false;
});

$("form[name='" + CollegeReview._enum.SeachForm + "']").live('submit', function () {
    CollegeReview.PopulateForReview();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Uhm, are'nt you returning false in the submit handler ?

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.live()` unless you're using some older version of jQuery

Comment: you are submitting the form by `input[type="image"]`. Isn't it should be `input[type="submit"]`

Comment: No, it shouldn't since `image` attr is for custom submit button

Comment: returning false in this case shouldn't be a problem. 

.on() or .live() shouldn't be a problem in this case. I have to use live as this site is using jquery 1.4.2.

@kidwon is correct, image attribute is for custom submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$("input[type='image']").live('click', function(){
    $("form[name='"+CollegeReview._enum.SeachForm+"']").submit(function(){
        CollegeReview.PopulateForReview();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Will it handle "return hit" in the text box?

Comment: Absolutely if you `trigger click` of `input[type='image']`.

Comment: Following worked on button click only. It is not working on "return hit" and again that is only on IE 9.0.11.

$("#"+ CollegeReview._enum.SearchFormButton).live('click', function(){
     CollegeReview.PopulateForReview();
     return false;
 });

Comment: So between 2 different triggers, its either one or the other in IE9.0.11

Comment: I'll mark this as selected answer. It at least activated the button click for IE 9.0.11.